# Misconception with Fourier Transforms in a Gaussian Light source?

Tags: optics, laser, fourier-transform, interference, interferometry

So for a Michaelson Interferometer , we know that the (complex) interferogram ($I=I(\Delta)$, $\Delta$=path difference between two mirrors) is related to the intensity profile of the light source $(I_S=I_S(\tilde{\nu}),\tilde{\nu}=1/\lambda$ denotes the wave number) by a Fourier Transform
$$I(\Delta)=\frac{1}{2}\int I_S(\tilde{\nu})exp(-i2\pi\tilde{\nu}\Delta)d\tilde{\nu}, 0<\tilde{\nu}=\frac{1}{\lambda }<\infty \tag{1}$$
The detected intensity is then $Re(I(\Delta))$.
[[image: Source: http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~bob/Term_Reports/Liu_2012.pdf]][1

I am asked to predict the gaussian profile width ($\delta \Delta$) of the interferogram for the green laser below:

[image: Source: Thorlab Green Laser Spec]

But the problem is that this spectrum is a Gaussian for the intensity in terms of the wavelength $I_S=I_S(\lambda)$ only,
not in terms of the wavenumber $I_S(\tilde{\nu})$ so the x-axis is
different? Which means diagrams (a), (b) ($\delta \tilde{\nu}=1/ \delta \Delta$)cannot be applied here because $I(\Delta)$ will no longer be a Gaussian (with beats in the profile) since the x-axis is now inverted $\lambda$? How do I find the Gaussian of the inteferogram $I(\Delta)$?

Comment: Image Source for the first two plots: http://www.physics.drexel.edu/~bob/Term_Reports/Liu_2012.pdf                      Second plot: Thorlab Green Laser Spec

Comment: I think you are to assume that the spectrum is Gaussian.  Note that the spectrum at the top does not appear to be Gaussian, but the plot of the coherence does.  In other words, don't sweat the details.  Make whatever assumptions needed to make progress.  And note the assumptions made in your solution.   The answer you get will not be exactly right, *but it will be very close*.

Comment: @garyp It's just that it doesn't make sense to me mathematically, how can the  bottom spectrum yield a Gaussian profile at the detector when the x axis is different (inverse of $\tilde{\nu}$)?

Comment: Would it make more sense to you if you recast the spectrum in frequency (or wavenumber) space?

Comment: @garyp
oh I see, so you're saying that I should do a Fourier transform from $\lambda \to \tilde{\nu}$ to obtain $I_S(\tilde{\nu})$? Initially I thought that if $I_S(\lambda)=I_{S0}exp(-\frac{(\lambda-\lambda_0)^2}{2(\delta \lambda)^2})$ then $I_S(\tilde{\nu})$ would simply be $I_{S0}exp(-\frac{(1/\tilde{\nu} -1/\tilde{\nu}_0)^2}{2 (\delta \lambda)^2})$ which cannot be Gaussian.

Comment: @garyp
But how does that work mathematically though? Why can I not just substitute $\tilde{\nu}=1/\lambda $ to obtain $I_S(\tilde{\nu})$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that $I_s(\nu)$ isn't Gaussian with respect to $\nu$ if $I_s(\lambda)$ is Gaussian with respect to $\lambda$. That said, $I_s(\nu)$ is *approximately* Gaussian if you have a sufficiently narrow bandwidth.

To see this, consider the Taylor series of expansion of $\lambda = 1/\nu$ around $\lambda_0 = 1/\nu_0$. We see that

$\lambda = \frac{1}{\nu_0} - \frac{1}{\nu_0^2} (\nu - \nu_0) + O((\nu - \nu_0)^2)$

or in other words,

$\Delta \lambda \approx - \frac{\Delta\nu}{\nu_0^2}$

where $\Delta \lambda = \lambda - 1/\nu_0 = \lambda - \lambda_0$ and $\Delta\nu = \nu - \nu_0$.

So when $\Delta\nu$ is small, we can write that

$I_s(\nu) = I_{s0}e^{-\Delta\lambda^2 / (2(\delta\lambda)^2)} \approx I_{s0}e^{-\Delta\nu^2 / (2(\delta\lambda)^2 \nu_0^4)}$

which is Gaussian in $\nu$.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to do a variable substitution $\tilde{\nu} ->\lambda$ in your integral .

From $\tilde{\nu}=1/\lambda$ you get
$$\frac{d\tilde{\nu}}{d\lambda} = -\frac{1}{\lambda^2}$$

i.e.

$$d\tilde{\nu} = -\frac{d\lambda}{\lambda^2}$$

and therewith

$$I_\lambda(\Delta)=\frac{1}{2\lambda^2}\int I_S(\lambda)exp(-i2\pi\Delta/\lambda)d\lambda,\quad 0<\lambda<\infty \tag{1}$$

Note that the minus sign has disappeared because the integration limits have been exchanged as well.

As for the example spectrum shown: this does actually not look anything like a Gaussian, as it is clearly not symmetrical.